# How to read in list from file in R?

Tags: r, list, types

I have list written in file created by sink() - "file.txt". That file contains one list, which look like this, and it contains only numers:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2
[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

how to read in data as list from such file ?

**EDITION :**
I'm going to try read it as a string, then use some regex to remove `'[[*]]'` and substitute `'[*]'` with special symbol - let it be `'@'`. Then take every substring between `'@'`, split it into vector and put into empty list.

Comment: It is a only human-readable representation of the object: trying to convert it back to a list will be cumbersome and error-prone. It is safer and easier to save it as an object, either with `save`/`load` or, if you want something both portable and human-readable, `toJSON`/`fromJSON` from the `RJSONIO` package.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that someone saved list that way (using sink() ) and now I have to read it as list again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. (The exact details may vary, but at least this will give you some ideas to work with.)

```
l <- readLines("file.txt")

l2 <- gsub("\\[{2}\\d+\\]{2}", "@", l)          # Replace [[*]] with '@'
l3 <- gsub("\\[\\d+\\]\\s", "", l2)[-1]         # Remove all [*]
l4 <- paste(l3, collapse=" ")                   # Paste together into one string
l5 <- strsplit(l4, "@")[[1]]                    # Break into list
lapply(l5, function(X) scan(textConnection(X))) # Use scan to convert 2 numeric
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 3
```